# JavaScript - Regex to remove spaces within the parentheses except spaces within single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I need your help to remove spaces within the parentheses except spaces within single quotes using `regex` in replace method in `JavaScript`.

```
Input - substringof('John', name) eq true
Output - substringof('John',name) eq true

Input - substringof('John' ,name) eq true
Output - substringof('John',name) eq true

Input - substringof('John ' , name) eq true
Output - substringof('John ',name) eq true
```

I tried some `regex` but I was unable to get what I need.

Comment: @Ghoti trim() will remove start and trail spaces. What i am looking for is the regex should help in removing the spaces within parentheses () except the space inside single quotes inside the parentheses ()

Comment: @Bravo You are correct. I have to provide something to the replace method to remove those space and regex is the answer, right?

Comment: Correct. I have updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/63Y4FX I tried to capture everything inside parentheses with the help of other answers but not quite able to select only white space.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not possible with a single RegEx.

You could try to extract the parts of the string from which you want to remvoe whitespace with:

```
\((.*?)'.*'.*?\)
```

This captures the characters between the opening parenthesis and the opening single quote in a first capture group, and the characters between the closing parenthesis and the closing single quote in the second capture group.

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/q1krmG/1/

You can the trivially remove the whitespace from these parts of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using `replacerFunction`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```js
const input = "substringof( 'John ' , name ) eq true"

const output = input.replace(/\((.*),(.*)\)/, (m, p1, p2) => `(${p1.trim()},${p2.trim()})`)

console.log(output)
```

Using `regex` alone

https://regex101.com/r/oroU4l/1

```js
const input = "substringof( 'John ' , name ) eq true"

const output = input.replace(/\(\s*(.*?)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*\)/, '($1,$2)')

console.log(output)
```